# Key mismatch on Apache server when there should not be

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl

So I've tried dealing with support on this with no luck. They're confirmed that my certificate and private key are matching.

My FQDN is also the same as in the certificate - I'll just call it domainname.com here.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 & Apache 2.2 something (I know, old. I'll upgrade soon).

I am getting this error:

```
[Mon Jul 17 23:40:23 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `domainname.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Jul 17 23:40:23 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `domainname.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Jul 17 23:40:23 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `domainname.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Jul 17 23:40:23 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `domainname.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Jul 17 23:40:23 2017] [error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Mon Jul 17 23:40:23 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

However:

```
/var/log/apache2# hostname
domainname.com
```

Both Comodo & myself have tested the certificate & private key and they match (myself here: https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html).

I am wondering if maybe it is the SSLCertificateChainFile file.

I created it with the following command:

```
cat COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSe cureServerCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > 82370186.ca-bundle
```

What could possibly be going on here that I haven't tested?

Comment: Is it possible you have an alias set-up in your Apache config? Also check you have RSA in the `SSLCipherSuite` in the Apache config.

Comment: My Apache/server setup knowledge is always a little hit or miss. How would I check those things exactly?

Comment: How did you configure this server if you did not edit the Apache config? See: [Where is my httpd.conf file located apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache)

Comment: Oh, I have a separate config for each of my domains in sites-enabled/sites-available. My apologies. And my ServerAlias is also domainname.com. I do not appear to have SSLCipherSuite anywhere, though this hasn't been a problem before (I've had SSL certs installed previously and it worked fine)